# Sonar scanner plugin installation

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-api

I have sonar-scanner-3.0.0.702 in local and sonar qube v5.3 in remote server.

In my sonar config property i have mentioned as like below.

```
sonar.host.url=https://example.com/sonar
sonar.token=a2s3d4f4k57
sonar.login=someuser
sonar.password=somepassword
sonar.language=abc,xyz
```

When I run the sonar scanner by executing ..\bin\sonar-scanner.bat. I can see the jar's are getting downloaded from site and saved under cache folder(C:\Users\John.sonar\cache). But my custom languages jar will not be downlaoded and hence it is throwing error saying

`ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'abc,xyz'

1) How can i plugin my custom JAR files in sonar scanner to make it work ?

Note : I know the procedure to include custom jar file in sonar Qube (sonarqube-5.3\extensions\plugins).But how can we do it for sonar scanner ?

2) In my conf file, i have mentioned sonar.token and sonar.password. if i remove the password i am getting authentication error. Why sonar scanner not using token for authorization ? how can we overcome this error ?

`ERROR: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password`